# Problems with booting Ubuntu live CD in serial console in QEMU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, qemu

I'm trying to boot up a Ubuntu live CD as a virtual machine, using `qemu`. The host system is also Ubuntu (Jammy). The system boots up OK in graphical mode, but (for reasons) I want to boot it in headless mode where the only peripheral output is the serial port.

I have done something like that already on a Mac (Apple Silicon) as a host system, without any problems. Unfortunately, I can't make the same thing work on Ubuntu. I'm starting up the VM with this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -nodefaults \
  -machine q35,accel=kvm \
  -cpu host \
  -smp 2 \
  -m 2G \
  -chardev vc,id=monitor \
  -mon monitor \
  -serial vc \
  -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd \
  -cdrom jammy-desktop-amd64.iso
```

The boot menu shows up nicely:

[image: GRUB menu in QEMU]

I can navigate around it, but when I hit enter, the screen becomes blank. I managed to confirm that the system **does** boot up properly, it's just that the serial console remains silent from this point on:

[image: QEMU blank serial console]

What I expected to see is the kernel output and login prompt in the serial console, like here:

[image: QEMU serial console Ubuntu login prompt]

I tried connecting the serial console in many different ways, e.g. by using `stdio` instead of `vc`, with no avail.

This problem seems somehow related to GRUB and its menu. When I boot up a cloud image (a QCOW2 file mounted as a disk), which launches directly (without GRUB menu), everything works fine.

What's going on?